# How to do Modulus with Fractions

Tags: modulus

I understand the modulus function (%), but not how it works with certain values. I see why 1%2 = 1 but not other cases. For example, why is 4%5 = 4  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think of Modulus as the remainder after division.
For example:

`1%2` can be looked at as "1/2 = 0 (1 cannot be divided evenly by 2), we have a remainder of **1**". Modulus = `1`.

`4%5` can be looked at as "4/5 = 0 (4 cannot be divided evenly by 5), we have a remainder of **4**".  Modulus = `4`.

`4%2` can be looked at as  "4/2 = 2 (4 can be divided evenly by 2 twice) with a remainder of **0**". Modulus = `0`.

`5%2` can be looked at as "5/2 = 2 (5 can be divided evenly by 2 twice) with a remainder of **1**".  Modulus = `1`.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense, so 8%10 is 8 because it divides 0 times but still has 8 left over. Thank you